# POST without body on DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am writting an API on Django Rest Framework to follow users. I define a method POST method to follow, but a body is required. I want to do without body or a default body. If I replace POST with GET works, If is it possible and how can I do?

```
class UserProfileViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('name', 'email')
    permission_classes = (UpdateOwnProfile,)

    @action(methods=['POST'], detail=True, url_path='follow')
    def follow(self, request, pk=None):
        user_to_follow = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=pk)
        request.user.add_relationship(
            user_to_follow, RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING)
        return Response([], status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: What do you mean by a body being required? If you're getting an error can you add the traceback to the question?

Comment: It is not an error. I only want to not send a body when I use POST method. When I follow a user, I think that a POST method is more semantic. If is not possible, I will use GET instead.

Comment: @Francisco Martin I want what exactly you mentioned in question, like I want to use POST method, but don't want to show body part on swagger doc. Where you able to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

If your serializer class `serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer` has fields that are required then the form body is required. If you don't want them to be required you can explicitly disable it or make the fields readonly with `seralizers.ReadOnlyField()`

If you are getting an error, showing your stacktrace would help in resolving it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a CBV as the following

```
class SomeView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = SomeSerializer

    def post(self, request, some_id):
        ...
```

to achieve what you want it should be sufficient to change the `serializer_class` value to None.

```
class SomeView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = None

    def post(self, request, some_id):
        ...
```

Then you will see in the DRF web ui that no body has to be added to the POST request.